# Переопределение метода onMeasure

Tags: android, java

У меня есть кастомная вьюшка. Как полагается, я переопределяю метод `onDraw` и `onMeasure`.  Метод `onMeasure` выглядит так:

```
int w = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
int h = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
```

Я не могу разобраться, что означает параметры `widthSpec` и `heightSpec`. Например, я нашел, что есть три константы:

```
public static final int UNSPECIFIED = 0;
public static final int EXACTLY = 1073741824;
public static final int AT_MOST = -2147483648;
```

Но мне приходит значения этих `spec-` равное 1073742704 (т.е. 0x40000370 в 16-ричной системе). Что означает это значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это результат выполнения функции `makeMeasureSpec`, которая как раз упаковывает размер и спецификацию вместе. Это сделано для экономии памяти (как написано в источнике) функции `pack` и `unpack`.

Чтобы получить `mode` воспользуйтесь функцией:

```
getMode(int measureSpec)
```

Похожая функция есть для получения `size`:

```
getSize(int measureSpec)
```

Описания этих функций [здесь](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html)